# Phonegap window.open insert innerHTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

I like to add innerhtml content(Just Anchor Link) when an external website is opened.

Below code is used to open the external site in inAppBrowser.
var ref = window.open(url, '_blank', 'location=yes');

I tried with below code to add the innerhtml but its not adding the content to the opened website. Can you please suggest an solution?

```
ref.addEventListener('loadstop', function() {
  //Page loaded! some code here..
  ref.executeScript({
    code: "var evaluateFeedback =   
    function() {
    return 'Done';
  };
  "},

    function(data) {
    ref.document.body.innerHTML =
      "<b>Hello, stackoverflow!   < /
    b > ";

  }
  );
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ref` is a reference to the `inAppBrowser` object, you can't do `ref.document.body.innerHTML` because the `inAppBrowser` object doesn't have a document property

You are using `executeScript` in the wrong way, the code you want to inject is the code on the code param.

If you do it this way it will work:

```
var ref = cordova.InAppBrowser.open('http://apache.org', '_blank', 'location=yes,toolbarposition=top');
ref.addEventListener('loadstop', function() {
    ref.executeScript({code: "document.body.innerHTML = '<b>Hello, stackoverflow!</b>';"});
});
```

But that will replace your website content with just the Hello, stackoverflow! message, if you want to append it, you should use

```
var ref = cordova.InAppBrowser.open('http://apache.org', '_blank', 'location=yes,toolbarposition=top');
ref.addEventListener('loadstop', function() {
    ref.executeScript({code: "document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML +'<b>Hello, stackoverflow!</b>';"});
});
```